# Asp.net Menu remove bullets

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I cannot get rid of the bullets. 
I have tried to use the liststyle equals none to no avail
Any Suggestions.This is my html

```
<asp:Menu ID="SiteMainMenu"  runat="server" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="menuItemS"
                        StaticHoverStyle-BackColor="#F8941C" DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="menuItemD"
                        DynamicHoverStyle-CssClass="DynamicStyle" DynamicHorizontalOffset="10" DynamicVerticalOffset="4"
                        DynamicMenuItemStyle-Height="20" DynamicHoverStyle-BackColor="#FAA53D" EnableViewState="false"
                        IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100%">
                        <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Pages/graphs/monthlyservicesales.aspx" Text="Graphs">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports">
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Pages/reports/monthlyservicetypesalesmoneyreport.aspx"
                                    Text="Daily Sales"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Pages/reports/monthlyservicetypesalesmoneyreport.aspx"
                                    Text="Reports"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Pages/reports/monthlyservicetypesalesmoneyreport.aspx"
                                    Text="Reports"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                        </Items>
                    </asp:Menu>
```

and this is my css that controls the menu.It works nicely except for the bullets that are displayed.

```
   .AdminMenu 
{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:-129px;
    padding-top:3px;
    background:url(../Images/subHeaderBg.png) repeat-x;
}
#AdminMenuItems
{
    color:#000;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:11px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:8px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use `ClientIDMode='Static'` in your markup, to get sure that **SiteMainMenu** would be the real id of the corresponding HTML element. Then, you can use **everything selector** to override the default behavior of list items style beneath this element:

```
#SiteMainMenu *
{
   list-style: none; // A simple CSS reset in the scope of SiteMainMenu element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the menu does not use the styles that you have defined; none of the properties refer to `#AdminMenuItems` as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `list-style:none` for `menu ul`, not for `menu items`.

something like this:

```
#SiteMainMenu ul
{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:-129px;
    padding-top:3px;
    background:url(../Images/subHeaderBg.png) repeat-x;
    list-style:none;
}
```

In your html your menuid is `SiteMainMenu` not `AdminMenu`.

Hope this helps.